# Codeigniter still shows index.php after forcing https

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, https, base-url

Just launched my site with an SSL certificate.  When I go to the https site it works perfectly.  However if I force just http, even after configuring htaccess, it forwards me to the https site, but it adds `index.php?/` to the end of the url.  For example if I go to `http://www.my-site.com` it redirects to `https://www.my-site.com/index.php?/`.  Of course the site works fine, its just a bit of an eyesore in the  url field.

base_url variable is as shown:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http' . ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? 's' : '').'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].str_replace('//','/',dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'/');
```

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php?|_assets|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml|favicon\.ico?)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I added the last 2 lines after researching how to force https when a visitor visits the site with http.

What am I missing?  htaccess is not my strong suit.  It's shared access otherwise I'd edit my `httpd.conf`

EDIT:
Updated `htaccess` looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This technically works, but for some reason when I access the site using `http` it redirects to the `https` version but concatenates another copy of my URI to the end.  For example if I go to `http://example.com/products` it redirects to `https://example.com/products?/products`.

Comment: $config['index_page'] ?

Comment: `$config['index_page'] = '';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third line of htaccess should be:
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1`
1. The question mark (?) shouldn't be there, anyway.
2. The [L] flag means last. When this rule is applied, no other directive runs.
So, the fifth line never runs, but this fifth line is the one which removes the index.php from the url.

Comment: Good to know!  I did what you said and now when I go to http://my-site.com it redirects to https but the page says `NO INPUT FILE SELECTED`

Comment: Weird, when i remove the ? from htaccess it breaks

Comment: It works, but it acts strange when I try to access the site with http.  It redirects to https but it changes the URI. For example if I go to my-site.com/about/contact it redirects to https but changes the url to my-site.com/about/contact?/about/contact.  The only wait to prevent that is to comment out the last 2 lines you suggested starting with `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off`

Comment: 1. After editing the .htaccess file, the browser cache must be cleared. 2. About the ?, it shows that the code is written to expect it in the url. Normally we don't want it.

Comment: When I remove the question mark from `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1` it completely breaks the site.  I get the error 'No input file specified.'.  So strange.

If I uncomment the last two lines (starting with `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off`) it works, but it changes the URI (for example my-site.com/about/contact?/about/contact).  It adds a copy of the URI to the end of the URI.

Comment: Edited my answer. Deleted slash (/) before index.php, because apache would read is as an absolute path and would search for an index.php in document_root.

Comment: This works (it worked before deleting the slash), but when I try to access the site with `http` it redirects to `https` but it concatenates and extra copy of my URI at the end. For example when I go to `http://my-site.com/products` it redirects to `https://my-site.com/products?/products`.  I've updated the full htaccess code above.

Comment: Finally figured it out after trial and error.  `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1` should have been `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php`.  Looks like its redirecting and removing `index.php` like it should be now.  Thanks!